# How to implement oAuth2 between mobile app ASP.NET Web Api and external login provider

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, google-signin

Imagine we want to implement architecture following the [oAuth2 protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50612_01/doc.11122/oauth_guide/content/images/oauth/oauth_overview.png). We have ASP.NET Web API as a service and external identity provider, e.g. Google. Now my client navigates to google, gets an access token and makes a request to my REST service. How do I verify this token? How do I make my Web Api trust Google's tokens?

I have a sample which uses [Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer) as identity provider (security token service) and I have my Web Api running as OWIN middleware which makes a reference to the identity server(from the Startup.cs class) and in this way it actually trusts it so every token issued by Identity Server is understandable from my REST service. How do I achieve this if I wanted to make a direct call to Google's login and use it as 3rd party provider?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to use openID rather than OAuth directly. You need to verify the openID claim in order to validate the token http://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-validate-an-openid-connect-id-token

Comment: See also http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Comment: @Paulw11 If we assume that the token itself contains any information commonly represented by claims and claims are grouped into scopes. Then OpenId, which is like extension to oAuth2, adds a new scope - identity. If my REST service doesn't really need to know that but only needs to know this user is already verified somewhere else I would like just to know that, no matter what is his id, what is the issuer etc. I just need to know that this user is not someone anonymous.

Comment: Then you can validate the token with the tokenInfo endpoint - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth  Calling the token auth url like https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 should give you a 200 response and a JSON document that describes the token

Comment: @Paulw11 This one really looks like something that I could use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the way you code this kind of scenario could work like this :

1. you create a google application and get your access keys and set the return url
2. Your front end redirects the user to Google's login page, passing your app access keys.
3. Google authenticates the user then calls your application with an authorization code.
4. You then hit Google with this code and receive an access token.
5. With the access token you can now hit Google's API and retrieve whatever information you have access to and can find out more about the user. It is normal at this point to create a link between your own membership system and Google's OAuth2 system. You would store the token for later calls and later you can use the refresh_token mechanism to keep talking to Google's API if you need to.

With all this in mind you would obviously not need your own Authorization Server, but you still need the Resource Server ( which is basically your own REST API ) and build your own middleware so it can understand Google's or any other provider's tokens, it can talk to Google's API etc.

You would implement your own version of the [Authorize] tag so your system could still work in a similar way except you don't use Owin any more.